# Move last N files from folder in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I was wondering - is there a nice and elegant way in Windows 8.1 to move last N files from a folder to another folder other than writing a program to do it?

*Edit:*
N is, for example, 100, and the files are sorted by name.

Comment: it depends on the file names or the "N". `movethisfiles1.txt, movethisfile2.txt, etc...` Yes. It's called a wildcard > `movethisfile*.txt` If there's no rhyme or reason to the last "N" filenames, then there's no way that I know of. There MAYBE some copy, xcopy, robocopy flag that does this but I strongly doubt you can do the required task without writing some basic script.

Comment: How do you define the last `N`? By name? By size? By creation date? ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, I meant last N (100, for example), when the files are sorted by name.

Comment: @Eutherpy please [edit] your question to include the extra information from you comment.

Comment: Just sort by most recent and highlight the most recent 100

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I move last N files from a folder?

> N is, for example, 100, and the files are sorted by name.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
rem parameters
rem %1 number of files to move
rem %2 source directory
rem %3 target directory
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem initialise number of files
set count=0
rem count files
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir %2 /a-d /b /O:N') do @(set /a count+=1 >nul)
rem set number of files to skip (not move)
set /a "skip=count-%1"
rem move the files
for /f "skip=%skip% delims=" %%a in ('dir %2 /a-d /b /O:N') do echo move %2\%%a %3\%%a
```

Remove the `echo` from `do echo move...` when you are happy the batch file is working to your satisfaction.

Usage:

```
test N Source Target
```

Where:

- `N` number of files to move
- `Source` source directory
- `Target` target directory

Example:

```
C:\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8D0-DF1E

 Directory of C:\test

31/05/2015  11:31    <DIR>          .
31/05/2015  11:31    <DIR>          ..
26/05/2015  18:20               117 address.out
26/05/2015  18:16               265 data.txt
31/05/2015  11:25    <JUNCTION>     junction [f:\test]
31/05/2015  11:31    <DIR>          sub
31/05/2015  18:16               449 test.cmd
               3 File(s)            831 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  95,480,258,560 bytes free

C:\test>test 1 . c:\temp
move .\test.cmd c:\temp\test.cmd
C:\test>
```

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: He wants the last N files when they're sorted by name, but I don't seem to see that sorting performed anywhere.

Comment: @karan dir /b sorts by name ...

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to, not here at least. Why would we have /O then?

Comment: @karan it does for me I just double checked. In any case I will update answer later when I have internet on laptop.

Comment: On some directories I get sorted output but not on others. I suspect it's simply displaying based on the order of entries in the file table. Otherwise I see no reason for dir to have a switch for sorting by name.

Comment: Answer updated to force sort by name as per comments by @karan

Comment: @karan you are correct, from https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true "If you omit /o, dir displays the names in the order in which they occur in the directory."

Comment: Good job digging up an official reference. :)